Take screenshot in gnome environment via its dbus api
I'm trying to take a screenshot using the gnome dbus api https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/blob/main/data/org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot.xml
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

int main(void)
{
    GDBusProxy *proxy;
    GDBusConnection *conn;
    GError *error = NULL;
    conn = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, &error);
    g_assert_no_error(error);

    proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_sync(conn,
                  G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
                  NULL,             /* GDBusInterfaceInfo */
                  "org.gnome.Shell",        /* name */
                  "/org/gnome/Shell",   /* object path */
                  "org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot", /* interface */
                  NULL,             /* GCancellable */
                  &error);
    g_assert_no_error(error);

    int success;
    char filename_used[100];

    g_dbus_proxy_call_sync(proxy,"Screenshot",
    g_variant_new ("(bbsbs)", TRUE, FALSE, "/tmp/screenshot",&success,filename_used),
                G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                -1,
                NULL,
                &error);
    g_assert_no_error(error);
    return 0;
}

the error: ERROR:dbus-stack.c:33:main: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method ?Screenshot? (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Bail out! ERROR:dbus-stack.c:33:main: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method ?Screenshot? (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Aborted (core dumped)
obviously I'm doing something wrong

I haven't tested my solution, but you are using wrong object_path, correct one is /org/gnome/Shell/Screenshot. Also the method accepts only three input parameters, so g_variant first parameter should be "(bbs)".
You can use d-feet to introspect names, this can be very helpful for you. Please let me know if this is the correct answer, otherwise I will test it myself.

yes that helped, thanks
At first there was an error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied, but if you switch to unsafe mode, the screenshot is taken successfully
Is it possible to take a screenshot like this without going into unsafe mode?
